# Restore a psql dump to an other (new) database name -d/--dbname and -f/--file cannot be used together

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I have dumped a PostgreSQL database using:

```
pg_dump --file "dump_file.sql" \
        --host "localhost" \
        --port "5432" \
        --username "username" \
        --verbose \
        --format=c \
        --blobs \
        --encoding "UTF8" \
        --schema "public" \
        "dbname"
```

Then when I try to restore it:

```
pg_restore --file "dump_file.sql" \
           --clean \
           --create \
           --no-privileges \
           --no-owner \
           --format=c \
           -U "username" \
           -d "newdatabasename"
```

it says:

```
pg_restore: error: options -d/--dbname and -f/--file cannot be used together.
```

And if I remove `-d "newdatabasename"` it says:

```
pg_restore: error: could not read from input file: end of file
```

#### Question

How could I restore this database under a new name?

After some readings, I thought `--no-privileges --no-owner` would have fixed it but it's not the case...

Comment: Per docs here [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) '--file filename Specify output file for generated script, or for the listing when used with -l. Use - for stdout.'. This is for restoring to a file not a database. Just include the filename by itself at end of connection string.

Comment: "`--create` ... When this option is used, the database named with -d is used only to issue the initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE commands. All data is restored into the database name that appears in the archive." https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: PS: Probably `ALTER DATABASE name RENAME TO new_name` could be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `pg_restore`, the dump file is *not* the argument to `--file`. It is not an option argument at all.

```sh
pg_restore --clean \
           --create \
           --no-privileges \
           --no-owner \
           --format=c \
           -U "username" \
           -d "newdatabasename" \
           "dump_file.sql"
```